# Variable template specialisation

Tags: c++, templates

I have a banded matrix class, which inherits from a abstract matrix class

```
template <typename T, std::size_t R, std::size_t B>
class BMatrix : public Matrix<T, R, R> {
    ...
};
```

I want to have a tridiagonal matrix class, how I have done this is as follows (using inheritance)

```
template <typename T, std::size_t R>
class TriMatrix : public BMatrix<T, R, 3> {
 ...
}
```

Now I am not sure whether this is the best thing to do (As there are VERY efficient methods for tridiagonal matrices but not so much general banded matrices). While the above works, I would like to use a template specialisation. However I am mixing template types and variables.

Is there a way in which I can do this without using inheritance ?

For instance something like

```
template <typename T, std::size_t R, >
class BMatrix<T, R, 3> {
 ...
} typedef TMatrix ??
```

Comment: If you don't want to use inheritance, just put that  "3" as internal variable and not template argument, and use the `using` directive instead of typedef. Anway, I don't see nothing wrong in your `TriMatrix` class

Comment: Not sure if it applies (not familiar enough with Matrix types), but care with [Circle-ellipse_problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem).

Comment: I see, are you basically saying that I should boycot the idea of inheriting Banded matrix stuff (ellipse) into tridiagonal matrix stuff (circle)? It makes sense for solving systems surrounding these matrices. 

tri/pentagonal methods have very efficient methods for solution as you can hardcode the formulas without things getting too crazy. 

From what I understand about template specialisation you have to reimplement everything from sratch, so that made sense over inheritance. then use typedef to get nice names.

Comment: I meant, that if Matrix is mutable and can change any value in it, tridiagonal matrix, vis inheritance would also allow to change its internal value (so no longer be tridiagonal, or not really do the "expected change") (as using Ellipse.stretchX from Circle).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly,
you might have your partial specialization:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t R>
class BMatrix<T, R, 3> {
 // ...
};
```

and an `using` facility

```
template <typename T, std::size_t R>
using TriMatrix = BMatrix<T, R, 3>;
```

Comment: What are the implications for using partial specialisation? Is it similar to full specialisation of type templates where I have to reimplement the methods of the fully templated class?.

Comment: partial/full specialization is similar for classes. and indeed, you would have to re-implement whole class (`private` base class might help to factorize common stuff).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in asserting that with specialization, you'll need to reimplement everything. There are some workaround using inheritance (both the generic BMatrix and specialized BMatrix could inherit from a common base), but I'd like to point out some alternative patterns.

Firstly, if you want to stick with your current class design using member functions for certain operations, you could simply implement everything in the generic class, and use `static_assert` to stop someone from using a specific method when `B!=3`. As class template member functions are not instantiated before they are actually used, you can safely have these functions in the generic case where they are not applicable. You can use `if constexpr` (or simply just `if` if both alteratives will compile) if you want to provide an more optimal implementation for an algorithm where a less optimal version already exists for the generic case.

```
template<int W, int H>
class Ellipse
{
    int Radius() const
    {
        static_assert(W==H); // only applies to circles
        return W;
    }

    float Circumference() const
    {
        if (W == H)
            return 2*PI*W;
        else
            return ... // ellipse circumference is not trivial
    }
};

// Handy type alias
template<int R> using Circle = Ellipse<R,R>;
```

Secondly, you could choose to not implement all the operations as class members, but rather use regular non-member functions. That way, you can fix certain parameters and use overloading:

```
// Radius, only for circles
template<int R>
int Radius(Ellipse<R,R> e) { return R; }

// Circumference, generic case
template<int W, int H>
int Circumference(Ellipse<W,H> e) { return /* ... */; }

// Circumference, specific case for circles
template<int R>
int Circumference(Ellipse<R,R> e) { return 2*PI*R; }
```

Comment: C++20 adds `requires` which allow to "discard" methods (as SFINAE does for template functions/methods): `int Radius() const requires(W == H)`